# Encoding Video for HTTP Live Streaming with Subtitles

Tags: ios, video-streaming, http-live-streaming

I've been following Apple's guide for [HTTP Live Streaming](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StreamingMediaGuide/UsingHTTPLiveStreaming/UsingHTTPLiveStreaming.html) and have it working nicely in my app but I'd like to embed subtitles in the video. [This thread on Quora](http://www.quora.com/Are-subtitles-closed-captions-supported-for-HTTP-Live-Stream-videos-on-Apple-iOS-devices) suggests that Netflix have done it.

My source videos have subtitles embedded via a .srt file using QuickTime Pro and the subtitles can be seen when playing the video in QuickTime and in my iOS app. Once I split the video into smaller .ts files using mediafilesegmenter (as required for HLS), the subtitles disappear. I'm using [MPMoviePlayerController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Is there a special way to encode the source video or to use mediafilesegmenter for subtitling to work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is possible to have captions in the ts stream (e.g. EIA-608 or EIA-708). I don't know of any good free tool for inserting such subtitles into a ts stream, but probably [Manzanita](http://www.manzanitasystems.com) will sell you something (for an absurd price).

Unfortunately, many HLS players will ignore the subtitles because the HLS specification has no mention of how subtitle tracks should be handled. In your own app, you can test it by finding a ts file that already contains EIA-608/EIA-708 text, and segmenting it.

To be frank, I think embedding subtitles in the TS is a dead end, and you'll find it easier to write your own subtitle displayer triggered by the TimedMetadata.

=== UPDATE ===

Since version 9 (September 22, 2012) of the HLS draft, WebVTT subtitles are supported in HLS. I don't know of any tool for preparing streams with them.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this is pretty much the conclusion I have reached. I have it mostly working with TimedMetadata now. I'd love to see Apple add proper support for subtitles to HLS but for now I think it's safe to assume it's not possible.

Comment: You can add closed caption in HLS streams using Apple Compressor which is around $50. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-r59sSiDBKU but yeah, webvtt is probably a better, there is an open source javascript project to edit them http://scottbw.wordpress.com/2011/06/28/creating-subtitles-and-audio-descriptions-with-html5-video/ and apple have provided them mediasubtitlesegmenter to split the .vtt files into smaller .vtt files for HLS

Answer (score 0):

I think for HTTP Live Streaming in a browser, there is no support for subtitles (I could be wrong).

However, there are polyfills like http://captionatorjs.com/ that allow subtitles in videos on iOS.  Now, I know captionator works for non-HLS video, however not sure if it works with HLS...you'd need to research/test.

---

P.S. if it's a native app you have, then you are looking for timed metadata http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPTimedMetadata_Class/Reference/Reference.html to support things like captions.

Comment: It's a native app - I have played with TimedMetadata but was hoping that HTTP Live Streaming has support for subtitles. I can't see why it wouldn't be possible to split the subtitles up and attach them to the individual media segments.

Answer (score 0):

In case it helps someone, I have an app that streams HLS content from a Vimeo Pro account. Vimeo allow you to add WebVTT subtitles which are handled perfectly well on iOS and tvOS devices.

To generate the .vtt file I used YouTube as shown here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vlj_Lq31BKw